# Input doesn't accept fractional values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to figure out how to make the input fields accept fractional values, for instance user can't enter right now 0.0007 as a percentage of 0.7%. Based on the code below, what would be the best solution to this issue? Thanks in advance

```
const parseNumber = number =>
    !Number.isNaN(number) && 
    Number(Number(number).toFixed(4));

export function PercentageInput({
    disabled,
    onChange,
    min,
    max,
    value,
    displayMin,
    displayMax,
}) {
    return (
        <div className={styles.percentageInput}>
            <input
                disabled={disabled}
                min={displayMin * 100}
                max={displayMax * 100}
                value={calculatePercentage({
                    min,
                    max,
                    value,
                    displayMin,
                    displayMax,
                })}
                data-test="parameter-input"
                className={styles.input}
                type="number"
                onChange={e => {
                    const newValue = parseNumber(e.target.value);

                    if (newValue || newValue === 0) {
                        onChange(
                            calculateAbsolute({
                                min,
                                max,
                                value: newValue,
                                displayMin,
                                displayMax,
                            })
                        );
                    }
                }}
            />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: I don't see a `step` property, which you'd need to set for decimals

Answer (score 0):

Step size is `1` by default. You will have to add a `step` attribute to `input`. You can change it as per your needed precision

```
<input type="number" step="0.001" ...>
```